# Is there any alternative of getLocality() method of Address class in android

Tags: java, android

getLocality() method is returning null value for some of the coordinates. Or if there is any other api for getting address so please let me know....
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi can anyone help me to solve it

Comment: try with NetWork Provider.. to getLocality...

Comment: hi Amitabh, I want to take Location by the Latitude and Longitude which I am getting from other source not from GPS.

Comment: below provide sample code for you..try it and give your feedback @MHSN

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this code...**

```
List<Address> addresses;

LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
//get the last known latitude longitude from network
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
//create an instance of geocoder
geo = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
{
    // Build the alert dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000000'>Location Service Not Active</font>"));

    builder.setMessage("Please Enable Location Services ");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
       {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            // Show location settings when the user acknowledges the alert dialog
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    alertDialog.show();

}

else
{
    addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
    if(addresses.get(0).getPostalCode() != null)
    {
        String currentZip = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        // currentZip which get gip code
    }
    else
    {
        // current zip not found
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support Amitabh. I have only one option to get the city that is by Latitude and Longitude by which I have to search the city. But now dont need city. so change the code accordingly.